# Potential Huggingface/bitsandbytes/Langchain/CUDA error: Error an illegal memory access was encountered at line 76 in file /src/csrc/ops.cu

Tags: langchain, huggingface

I'm running into an issue when loading a local model with huggingface that uses a bitsandbytes config. The error that gets output and code is the following:

```
def __init__(self, model_path: str, index_name: str, hf: bool = False):
    #load database
    print("loading database")
    os.system("nvidia-smi")
    embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings()
    db = FAISS.load_local(folder_path = "context", 
                          embeddings = embeddings, 
                          index_name = index_name,
                          allow_dangerous_deserialization = True)
    self.retriever = db.as_retriever()
    
    #load model and pipeline      
    print("loading model")
    tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path, add_eos_token = True)
    config = LoraConfig.from_pretrained(model_path)
    bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_4bit = True,
           bnb_4bit_use_double_quant = True,
           bnb_4bit_quant_type = "nf4",
           bnb_4bit_compute_dtype = torch.bfloat16)
    model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path, #config.base_model_name_or_path,
                                                      quantization_config = bnb_config,
                                                      device_map = "auto")


Loading checkpoint shards:   0%|             | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Error an illegal memory access was encountered at line 76 in file /src/csrc/ops.cu
```

I've tried loading a model directly from huggingface and while it can load the model attempting to run inference on it with langchain produces this error:

```
system = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm = model.llm, 
                                     chain_type = "stuff", 
                                     retriever = model.retriever, 
                                     chain_type_kwargs = args, 
                                     return_source_documents = True)

results = system(question)

RuntimeError: CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

I've tried reloading which version of cuda is being run, rebuilt the environment and packages. I'm not sure if its an issue with the libraries or CUDA itself. I made no changes to the code, hardware, or packages between my last successful run and when the error started showing up. Currently loaded on CUDA 12.1, this is the output of nvidia-smi before loading the model and after loading one succsesfully:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.129.03             Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:07:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P0              58W / 400W |      8MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:46:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0              60W / 400W |      8MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:85:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P0              59W / 400W |      8MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:C7:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0              63W / 400W |      8MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                     
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.129.03             Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:07:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P0              64W / 400W |   4172MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:46:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   29C    P0              66W / 400W |   4268MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:85:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   28C    P0              65W / 400W |   4268MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB          On  | 00000000:C7:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   30C    P0              69W / 400W |   2740MiB / 81920MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |             Disabled |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         


+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A   1791434      C   python                                     4158MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A   1791434      C   python                                     4254MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A   1791434      C   python                                     4254MiB |
|    3   N/A  N/A   1791434      C   python                                     2726MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```